# Is there any $C^1[0,1]$ function that satisfies equality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there any $C^1[0,1]$ function that satisfies the following equality?

$$\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt+f'(2/3)=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f(t)|+\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f'(t)|$$

Comment: Yes, $f(t)\equiv 0$.

Comment: I forgot to write that functions not equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_0^{1/2} f(t) dt  \leq \frac{1}{2}\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)| \leq \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$$
$$ f'(2/3)\leq \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)| $$

If we want equality, of the sum, we need both equalities at the same time. From the first one we get:
$$
\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)| = 0 \Rightarrow f(t) = 0
$$
so that this is the only possible solution.

Comment: It's better to say, if we assume that $\sup_{t\in[0, 1]}\lvert f(t) \rvert \neq 0$, then for any such function $f(t)$  it follows that 
$\int_0^{1/2} f(t) dt + f'(\frac{2}{3}) < \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)| + \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)| $. So if function that OP is looking exists it have to satisfy
$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)| + \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)| = 
\int_0^{1/2} f(t) dt + f'(\frac{2}{3}) < 
\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)| + \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)| $ which leads to contradiction. So our assumption fails, $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)| = 0$ and the only continuous function which has that property is $f(t) \equiv 0$.